# sass override default colors in bootstrap5 for a next.js?

Tags: typescript, bootstrap-4, sass, next.js

I have bootstrap loaded and working with my next.js app. I've been trying for days to override the default colors.

my global.scss file

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

$primary:#f3ced6;
```

I know that my scss file is connected tot he main app.js file, as all the styles work, including the new sass variables. I just can't get sass to override the default colors.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things here:

Could be that you haven't installed sass yet. If this is the case do:

`npm install sass`

**Change this**

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

$primary:#f3ced6;
```

**to**

```
// Custom variables
$primary:#f3ced6;

@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

You're adding variables after importing Bootstrap. Add them to the top, I usually create a file for this and do:

```
// Custom variables
@import "../scss/variables";

// Bootstrap core
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

As well create a file called `_variables.scss` where you can add your Bootstrap variables as usual.

To edit the colors you can override the theme colors like so:

```
$theme-colors: (
  "primary":    $primary,
  "secondary":  $secondary,
  "success":    $success,
  "info":       $info,
  "warning":    $warning,
  "danger":     $danger,
  "light":      $light,
  "dark":       $dark
);
```

You could change `"primary": $primary,` to `"primary": #f3ced6,` or you can use `$primary:#f3ced6;`(make sure this is at the top).